# Passing a function to a Worker (QObject) class in Python GUI application to prevent freezing/blocking

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to find a way to successfully pass a function to a Worker class in Python using PyQT5. Instead of using the pre-defined run function (or Long-running task) in the sample Worker class code, I would like to be able to pass a custom function to the worker class. Below I've pasted the sample code I'm working with, followed by an adjustment I've tried.

```
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal,Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QLabel,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout,QWidget
import sys

# Step 1: Create a worker class
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        for i in range(5):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i + 1)
        self.finished.emit()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clicksCount = 0
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Freezing GUI")
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Create and connect widgets
        self.clicksLabel = QLabel("Counting: 0 clicks", self)
        self.clicksLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.stepLabel = QLabel("Long-Running Step: 0")
        self.stepLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Click me!", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.countClicks)
        self.longRunningBtn = QPushButton("Long-Running Task!", self)
        self.longRunningBtn.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)
        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.clicksLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.stepLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.longRunningBtn)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

    def countClicks(self):
        self.clicksCount += 1
        self.clicksLabel.setText(f"Counting: {self.clicksCount} clicks")

    def reportProgress(self, n):
        self.stepLabel.setText(f"Long-Running Step: {n}")

    def runLongTask(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        self.thread.start()

        # Final resets
        self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.stepLabel.setText("Long-Running Step: 0")
        )

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, *init_args, **init_kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *init_args, **init_kwargs)
        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        self.finished.emit(self._return)
```

Comment: I ended up going with QProcess because I needed to run scripts from the terminal within my GUI and that seemed like the only option that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one of solutions, you can pass a function and an argument to the Worker's `__init__` method, like:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    result = pyqtSignal('QVariant')

    def __init__(self, function, args):
        super().__init__()
        self.function = function
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        res = self.function(self.args)
        self.result.emit(res)
        self.finished.emit()
```

So you can pass a method and an argument when creating a worker and connect the method to handle the result:

```
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker(Proxy.GetInfo, code)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.result.connect(self.receiveResult)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()
```